# Sql In clause Syntax Query error

Tags: sql

I want to extract messages for a single user from my messages table in database, the query that i have written has some syntax problem but i don't know how to fix it. please help

```
SELECT * 
FROM Messages 
WHERE SenderId = (SELECT UserId FROM Users WHERE ContactNo = 03005114812 ) 
   or ReceiverId = (SELECT UserId FROM Users WHERE ContactNo = 03005114812 ) 
   IN (SELECT * FROM Messages WHERE SenderId = 1 or ReceiverId = 1)
```

Comment: What are you trying to find? All messages between User 1 and the User with ContactNo=03005114812? If not that, then please add more explanation of what you're trying to find. Some sample data and expected results wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes sir i want to find the messages between user 1 and ContactNo= 03005114812

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for an `IN()` search

```
SELECT * 
FROM Messages 
WHERE
    (SenderId = (SELECT UserId FROM Users WHERE ContactNo = 03005114812 ) and
     ReceiverId = 1) or
    (ReceiverId = (SELECT UserId FROM Users WHERE ContactNo = 03005114812 ) and
     SenderId = 1)
```

Or alternatively:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM Messages m
       INNER JOIN
     Users u
        on
             (m.SenderId = u.UserId and m.ReceiverId = 1) or
             (m.ReceiverId = u.UserId and m.SenderId = 1)
WHERE
    u.ContactNo = 03005114812
```

which feels like it has a little less repetition to it.

Comment: Thanks Sir that worked. Don't mind I don't have any reputations to mark it correct but i have given it a vote. Thanksalot

Answer (score 1):

it's missing something

```
WHERE SenderId = (SELECT UserId FROM Users WHERE ContactNo = 03005114812 ) 
or ReceiverId = (SELECT UserId FROM Users WHERE ContactNo = 03005114812 ) 
<missing expression here> IN (SELECT * FROM Messages WHERE SenderId = 1 or ReceiverId = 1)
```

UPDATE could be e.g. id column if you have it in the `messages` table

```
WHERE SenderId = (SELECT UserId FROM Users WHERE ContactNo = 03005114812 ) 
or ReceiverId = (SELECT UserId FROM Users WHERE ContactNo = 03005114812 ) 
id IN (SELECT id FROM Messages WHERE SenderId = 1 or ReceiverId = 1)
```

Comment: i don't know sir what is missing i tried alot but invain